# Изменение отступа блока при появлении его в поле видимости

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Несколько дней назад изучал метод scroll смог указать: сместись влево, когда страница будет прокручена на 500рх вниз. Предполагая что когда я прокручу страницу на 500px я увижу как сместится блок.

Но решив усложнить задачу, столкнулся с такой проблемой: А если перед этим блоком будет еще один (резиновый блок) высота которого будет изменяться в зависимости от количества содержимого в нем. Тогда нужный нам блок может сползти вниз или подняться выше. И, когда к нему применятся соответствующие эффекты, мы их просто мы их просто можем не увидеть.

**Вопрос: как сделать чтобы блок     `<div class="totsamiy"></div>`
сместился от левого края на 150px при появлении его в поле видимости на высоте 150px от нижней части экрана.**

Вот выглядит это примерно так: https://jsfiddle.net/engenes/2b9eyn95/4/

```
<div class="rezinovi">
<h1>
Это наш резиновый блок
</h1>
Повседневная практика показывает, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности способствует подготовки и реализации направлений прогрессивного развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.
Не следует, однако забывать, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке дальнейших направлений развития. Равным образом консультация с широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. С другой стороны консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации направлений прогрессивного развития. С другой стороны укрепление и развитие структуры способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Равным обрНе следует, однако забывать, что консультация с широким активом в значительной степени обуславливает создание форм развития. Задача организации, в особенности же рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке существенных финансовых и административных условий. Разнообразный и богатый опыт укрепление и развитие структуры влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также консультация с широким активом играет важную роль в формировании новых предложений. Товарищи! новая модель организационной деятельности играет важную роль в формировании направлений прогрессивного развития.
Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с широким активом в значительной степени обуславливает создание позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также сложившаяся структура организации требуют от нас анализа форм развития.
Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности требуют от нас анализа системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Равным образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации соответствующий условий активизации.
Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что сложившаяся структура организации влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия. С другой стороны начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации соответствующий условий активизации. Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет оценить значение модели развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия.азом новая модель организационной деятельности требуют от нас анализа соответствующий условий активизации.

</div>
<div class="totsamiy">

</div>
```

не стал писать скрипт так как умею задавать жестко, то есть при прокрутке до указанных пикселей, нужный нам блок сместится, а других способов пока не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете на момонент scroll высчитывать насколько нужный вам блок находится на нужной стадии скрола. Вам помогут свойства `window.scrollY` - на сколько прокрутили `window.outerHeight` - высота окна и `el.offsetTop` - отступ элемента по высоте от начала документа.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
 var el = document.querySelector('.bottom-notice');
  if(window.scrollY + window.outerHeight - 150 > el.offsetTop) {
    //Элемент на нужной нам позиции
    el.style.marginLeft = '150px';
  }
});
```

Comment: забыл уточнить, надо больше чем на 150рх), но попытался вставить тот код, что вы дали, все равно почему-то не заработало. Можете на моем примере показать рабочий вариант?

Comment: Я проверил и этот код работает. Чуть исправил. Когда высота прокруктки + высота экрана - ваш отступ больше отступа по высоте нужного вам элемента, он сдвигается.

Comment: Еще чуть исправил селект) вы можете вставить прямо на этой странице в консоль этот код и описание под кнопкой 'Добавить еще один ответ" будет сдвигаться как вы хотите с .totsamiy

Comment: `var $block = $('.block');
$(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
 var top = window.scrollY + window.outerHeight;
  var paddingBottom = 150;
  if(top+paddingBottom > $block[0].offsetTop) {
   $block.addClass('active');
  } else {
   $block.removeClass('active');
  }
});`

Comment: все я пока ждал как раз написал примерно то же самое, все заработало, благодарю)))